# Error en Mysql: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES

Tags: java, sql, jsp

Estoy trabajando con JSP (Netbeans) y MySQL (PHPMyAdmin) usando XAMPP. Resulta que estoy haciendo un ejercicio, cuando voy a ejecutar el index.jsp, me sale en el navegador: Error en Mysql: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

No tengo contraseña en PHPMyAdmin, y mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Lista de Empleaods</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
        %>
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                <th scope="col">Direccion</th>
                                <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <%
                                try {

                                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ejemplo2?user=root&password=''");
                                    st = con.createStatement();
                                    rs = st.executeQuery("SEKECT * FROM empleado;");
                                    while (rs.next()) {
                            %>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><%= rs.getString(1)%></th>
                                <td><%= rs.getString(2)%></td>
                                <td><%= rs.getString(3)%></td>
                                <td><%= rs.getString(4)%></td>

                            </tr> 
                            <%
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    out.print("Error MySQL: " +e);
                                }
                            %>  

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Agradezco su atención y ojala puedan ayudarme con este problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el root user de la base de datos no tiene password, intenta con:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ejemplo2?user=root");
```